# Убрать заголовок и кнопки оставив возможность растягивать окно

Tags: c++, winapi

Есть окно

```
HWND hwnd = CreateWindowExW(
    WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW | WS_EX_TOPMOST,  // Optional window styles.
    CLASS_NAME,                        // Window class
    L"Keystrokes",
    WS_THICKFRAME,               // Window style

    // Position and size
    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 200, 200,

    NULL,       // Parent window    
    NULL,       // Menu
    hInstance,  // Instance handle
    nullptr     // Additional application data
);
```

Нужно сделать через стили так чтобы оно могло растягиваться как обычное окно но не имело заголовка и кнопок закрытия. Можно ли так сделать при учёте что WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW нужно оставить (WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW нужен для того чтобы не было значка на панели задач и при переключении через alt + tab) ?

(Что-то типа WS_POPUP но с возможностью растягивать окно)

Comment: Боюсь что возможность растягивать окно прийдётся запускать через SendMessage в обработчике клика.

Comment: А так можно? Как это сделать? Что за сообщение? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Вот https://stackoverflow.com/a/12071274/5727271 SendMessage прийдётся вставить в обработчик клика на окне.

Comment: Вы можете дать это как ответ и я его приму

Comment: Это не полное решение, надо ещё кучу кода дописать что бы это заработало. Возможно уже есть решение попроще, и кто-то ещё даст ответ.

Comment: Да, если лень регистрировать класс (тут не показан код регистрации), я чаще всего использую системный `"#32768"` - его винда использует для диалогов. Это позволяет сэкономить на RegistreClass, взамен приходится назначать WndProc вручную. Но для упрощения программы, думаю так проще. В некоторых случаях параметры при RegisterClass важны, но не в вашем случае.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Достаточно использовать стиль `WS_POPUP bitor WS_THICKFRAME bitor WS_VISIBLE`

Comment: Чего `bitor` а не `|` это же си

Comment: @nick_n_a в вопросе тег С++, но вообще-то bitor неплохо и в С использовать.

Comment: А вот эту штуку никак не убрать?
https://imgur.com/a/VVtXiyg

Comment: @AugustVishnevsky Так а это верхняя рамка в windows10 так рисуется. Остальные почему-то сделали прозрачными. В 7 по идее должны быть видны одинаковые рамки со всех сторон.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ <3

Comment: Попробуйте создать rgn квадратный, и сделать SetWindowRgn. Rgn позволит "отсечь" ненужную часть окна. Но rgn приёдется корректировать после resize. Прокатит ли достаточно большой - не пробовал. Что-то такое когда-то я делал.

Answer (score 0):

Как дополнение. Не лучше решение, но если прийдётся менять размеры почти в ручном режиме, то можно сделать форсированое изменение размера.  Что-то вроде... если клик попал в зону А - делать ресайз - лево-право. Но тогда прийдётся и вручную менять курсор и вручную обрабатывать клик.

Сам ресайз можно активировать/форсировать так

```
ReleaseCapture(); // Если мы делаем внутри  клика, то Capture может мешать
SendMessage(hwnd , WM_SYSMESSAGE, SC_SIZE + число , 0 );

/* где число
 SC_SIZE_HTLEFT = 1,
 SC_SIZE_HTRIGHT = 2,
 SC_SIZE_HTTOP = 3,
 SC_SIZE_HTTOPLEFT = 4,
 SC_SIZE_HTTOPRIGHT = 5,
 SC_SIZE_HTBOTTOM = 6,
 SC_SIZE_HTBOTTOMLEFT = 7,
 SC_SIZE_HTBOTTOMRIGHT = 8 */
// т.е. например так  
SendMessage(hwnd , WM_SYSMESSAGE, SC_SIZE + 8 , 0 );
```

Так же аналогично можно форсировать move

```
   ReleaseCapture(); 
   SendMessage(hwnd , WM_SYSMESSAGE, SC_MOVE + 2 , 0 );
```

И доп-совет по поводу region

```
HRGN rgn = CreateRectRgn(0,0,ширина_окна, высота_окна)
SetWindowRgn(w2, rgn , true);
... 
DeleteObject(rgn); // Потом регион прийдётся удалить
```

Не забудте при выходе, или обновлении уничтожать rgn, что бы не было утечки.
Возможно rgn можно создать на ширину/высоту экрана и не обновлять вообще, но я так не делал. Использование rgn позволяет "выкинуть" лишнюю часть окна и не показывать, т.е обрезать. Высоту заголока можно узнать через http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsystemmetrics

Comment: Спасибо большое, скорее всего так и придётся делать, не хочу чтобы та рамка выделялась. <3